# easy one... PHP image upload.... Can't remember syntax for getting a file into a specific folder

Tags: php

I have a cms I made for school a while ago that I am finally uploading live. While I had it on my local machine, I simply had the path to my image folder hardcoded as

```
$path = C:\path\to\my\uploads
```

Of course now that it is on a server, this will no longer work. I can't for the life of me remember the syntax of how to get it INTO the upload folder.

My images are simply landing with all of my other html and php files on the server instead of in my uploads folder. Then my image gallery is broken, because it looks for my thumbnails in my uploads folder.

I tried

```
$path = ..//uploads
```

and

```
$path = uploads
```

and

```
$path = //uploads
```

and none work.

I am feeling really stupid now.

Please help!

Comment: What kind of server? Windows or Unix?

Comment: And where is uploads relative to the rest of the code? Inside it? A level above?

Comment: have two different `$path` variable. One for upload, one for url, eg: `$upload_path` & `$upload_url`.

Comment: It's a windows server, and the structure is very simplistic. All files are on one level, the image folder is on that level as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `uploads` directory is at the same level as the rest of the code, it's easiest to simply do:

```
$path = "./uploads";
```

Windows will also accept

```
$path = ".\\uploads";
```

The `./` at the beginning isn't even really necessary if you're calling it from the directory in which it resides:

```
$path = "uploads";
```

But the first version `./uploads` is most portable and explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), you also shouldn't have to hardcode a path, even in local development, as the destination path is relative to the original executing script.